# Apex controller not called from inner component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-community

I have a lightning community where I am trying to update user record when the user clicks the specific button but what happens is when I call that controller from header it updates the records and the community loads up but when I call my controller from inner component It does not update record and community does not loads up at all

Here is the Component

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global" controller="POC_TrainingController">
<ltng:require scripts="/resource/jquery"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<div>
    <div class="slds-container_large slds-container_center">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">

                <lmsilt:Training />                  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</aura:component>
```

Here is Controller

```
({
reactivateUser : function(component, event, helper) {
     var action = cmp.get("c.reactivateUser");
action.setCallback(this, function(response){
    var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") 
        {
            console.log('SUCCESS');
        }
    else if(state === "ERROR")
    {
         console.log('ERROR');
    }
    else {
            console.log('There was a problem : '+response.getError());
        }

})
 $A.enqueueAction(action);
},


showVideo1 : function(cmp, event) {
    $("#video1").show();
},
closeModal : function(cmp, event) {
    $(".video-modal").each(function( index ) {
        $( this ).hide();
    });
}
})
```

Here is my apex class

```
public with sharing class POC_TrainingController {

@AuraEnabled
public static void reactivateUser()
{
List<GroupMember> gm = [SELECT ID from GroupMember WHERE Group.Name='PC Training DASH Upgrade' AND UserOrGroupId=:UserInfo.getUserId()];
if(UserInfo.getUserId()!=Null && gm.size()>0)
    {
    List<User> currentUser = [select Id,lmscons__Cornerstone_ID__c,CFS_Activation_Date__c,lmscons__CFS_Status__c from User where Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()];
    if(currentUser.size()>0 && currentUser[0].lmscons__Cornerstone_ID__c!=NULL && currentUser[0].lmscons__CFS_Status__c=='Deactivated')
        { 
            currentUser[0].lmscons__CFS_Status__c='Active';    
            currentUser[0].CFS_Activation_Date__c =  datetime.now();
        }
    update currentUser[0];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: When you say, ` but when I call my controller from inner component` is it `<lmsilt:Training /> `? If so, please can you paste the code for that component and it's controller? I hope that component also has the apex controller listed.

Comment: <lmsilt: Training/> is a component of the managed package.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the call-back function.
Have a look at the documentation.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm

Essentially you need to do something like,

```
doInit : function(cmp, event) {
    var action = cmp.get("c.reactivateUser");

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                //do your logic
            }
            else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                // do something
            }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + 
                                 errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Comment: I added the call back still no luck

Comment: Check the debug logs to confirm whether your apex method is firing. Also check you have `controller="POC_TrainingController"` defined on the component markup and also check your console logs whether there are any errors.

Comment: No, my method is not firing and I am including the controller="POC_TrainingController" markup

Comment: hmm interesting! can you provide your code for the full component and js controller?

Comment: Also it would help if you provide your main component as well as sub component. Is your button in the top level component?

Comment: I Updated the controller and the component

Comment: Ok thanks. All seems good. Are you sure your component is rendering on click of the button? May be add some text in the component and check whether it is coming up. It may be that you are not getting to the component at all to start with.